# Delphi 2010: EOleSysError 'Type mismatch' calling ActiveX control

Tags: delphi, activex

I have this C ActiveX API (don't have the sources just the binaries):

```
// \param a [out] Variant holding a byte array 
// \param b [out] Reference to a longlong (Signed 64-bit)
// \param c [out] Reference to a short
short foo(variant* a, longlong* b, short* c);
```

It's working fine in C#:

```
//auto-generated import:   
short foo(ref object a, ref long b, ref short c);

test {
 object a=null;
 long b=0;
 short c=0;
 foo(a,b,c); => OK 
}
```

NOK in Delphi 2010 (Note that *{??Int64}OleVariant* is added by the Delphi import tool):

```
//auto-generated import:
function foo(var a: OleVariant; 
             var b: {??Int64}OleVariant; 
             var c: Smallint): Smallint;

procedure Test;
var
 a, b: OleVariant;
 c: Smallint;
begin
 foo(a,b,c); => **EOleSysError 'Type mismatch' exception**
end;
```

Comment: according to this(http://www.netcoole.com/delphi2cs/datatype.htm) long = int64 in Delphi

Comment: also, longlong is a signed 64bit integer

Comment: @Dorin C/C++ long is 32 bits on Windows.

Comment: @David thank you, is that true for both 32 and 64 bit compiler?

Comment: @dorin yes it is. It's a key difference for C and C++ between windows and *nix. But I see now that your comment pertained to C# where long is 64 bit.

Comment: @David doesn't matter, I don't mind learning, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use predefined WinAPI types:

```
// C definition
short foo(variant* a, longlong* b, short* c);

// Delphi definition
function foo(var a: OleVariant; 
             var b: LongLong; 
             var c: Smallint); Smallint;

procedure FooTest;
var
  a: OleVariant;
  b: LongLong;
  c, RetVal: ShmallInt;
begin
  Retval := foo(a, b, c);
end;
```

`LongLong` is defined in `Windows.pas`, along with many, many other WinAPI compatible types. (At least they're in the `Windows` unit up through Delphi XE; XE2 may have relocated some of them due to cross-platform and 64-bit related relocations.)

```
// Windows.pas definition (Delphi 2010)
type
  LONGLONG = int64;
```

As David keeps mentioning in the comments below, `longlong` isn't a standard C++ datatype. However, based on the comments related to the parameters in your update, it's **exactly** what the C++ developer intended it to be, and therefore the WinAPI definition is compatible (and retains the same name for consistency for documentation purposes).

Comment: Smallint is what you want here to match short. As for longlong, that's not standard so we have to guess.

Comment: LONGLONG is not necessarily the same as longlong.

Comment: Arrgh! Thanks, David. Focused too much on `longlong`. (It's been around in the `Windows` unit for longer than `Int64` has been in Delphi, and was declared for compatibility with WinAPI documentation; I'd think that whoever wrote the C++ code was familiar with it from the API as well; otherwise they probably wouldn't have used it. :) Also, it's used in a C++ ActiveX library, which means a necessary familiarity with WinAPI compatible data types. I'd think the presumption that they were compatible would be safe until proven otherwise (by it not working).

Comment: The thing is, I've no idea what C++ `longlong` is. Do you know what it is?

Comment: It's being used in an ActiveX library, so I think a logical guess (and yes, it's a guess, but it's no more so than `int64` is) that it's a COM compatible type. `LONGLONG` is used in at least one place in the `ActiveX` unit, so it's apparently COM compatible. Are we splitting hairs here? ;)

Comment: `LONGLONG` and `longlong` are different. C++ is case-sensitive. What is `longlong`?

Comment: Yes, I know what the C++ developer intended it to be (see the edit to the original question). Pedantry aside, sometimes it's OK to make an educated guess.

Comment: Yes the update makes it even clearer. It was always clear it meant a 64 bit int. The proliferation of integer types defined in C++ and in the windows headers is truly ridiculous. It's much simpler and cleaner in C# or Delphi say.

Answer (score 1):

`longlong` is not a standard C++ type. I can't tell from the C++ code what type to use.

Now, in my view it's easier to work from the C# where the types are more intelligible and reliable than C/C++. In C# `long` is a signed 64 bit integer, so `Int64` in Delphi. The other two parameters in your Delphi snippet in the question are specified correctly.

Comment: Many thanks, it works using Int64. It seems obvious in retrospective, but it did not occur to me changing the imported ActiveX control, since it was auto-generated. I wonder why it puts a Variant, perhaps Delphi gets confused by the non-standard longlong?